# Why if I put the View at the bottom of a RelativeLayout, the RelativeLayout fills all the space?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to construct a "row" to be uses in my app.

In the "row" I use two Views to create an horizontal bar.

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventname"
    style="@style/T2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="nome evento" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventtype"
    style="@style/S2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="tipo evento" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/riga"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/riga"
    android:background="@color/lines" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

**So far so good.**

**BUT if I put the Views at the bottom:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventname"
    style="@style/T2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="nome evento" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventtype"
    style="@style/S2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="tipo evento" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/riga"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/riga"
    android:background="@color/lines" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the result I get

[image]

Please how do I solve this????

Thank you!!!

Comment: you need to read about RelativeLayout  more. There are many attributes which requires into your layout code.

Comment: @PankajKumar well... that's for sure...

Comment: what kind of view you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED!!!!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventname"
    style="@style/T2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="nome evento" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventtype"
    style="@style/S2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="tipo evento" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/rigagrigia"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eventtype"
    android:background="@color/lines" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/rigabianca"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/rigagrigia"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change layout to:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventname"
        style="@style/T2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="nome evento" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventtype"
        style="@style/S2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/eventname"
        android:text="tipo evento" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/riga"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/riga"
        android:background="@color/lines" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`riga` has already been declared, so you cannot use `@+id` again. To refer to already created id, use `@id/riga`.